# WooCommerce: How to show sale products outside loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a standard php page template for our shop, that should be used on a sales page on which are only shown products that are on sale. How can I display 4 random products on sale via php?

WooCommerce have a shortcode that displays sale products, but this doesn't work if I call it via do_shortcode function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your own query.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'showposts' => 4,
'orderby'   => 'rand',
'meta_query'   => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array( // Simple products type
        'key'     => '_sale_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '>',
        'type'    => 'numeric'
    ),
    array( // Variable products type
        'key'     => '_min_variation_sale_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '>',
        'type'    => 'numeric'
    )
)
);

$sale_products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Not sure why shortcode wouldn't be working.

```
echo do_shortcode('[sale_products columns="4" per_page="4"]' );
```